# Easy way to make std::compare functions unary

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to use different compare functions as unary functions, where one of the values is embedded inside the comparator. To do so I created an adaptor class, something like:

```
template<typename T, typename Compare>
class CompareAdaptor : private Compare
{
    public:
        CompareAdaptor(T value)
            : mValue(value)
        {
        }

        bool operator()(T v) const
        {
            return Compare::operator()(v, mValue);
        }

    private:
        T           mValue;
};
```

and now I can define a new unary comparator like:

```
template<typename T>
using EqualTo = CompareAdaptor<T, std::equal_to<T>>;
template<typename T>
using LessEqual = CompareAdaptor<T, std::less_equal<T>>;
```

My questions is: Is there a simpler way(without using the adaptor class) to define those unary comparators? I think this is a very common problem and probably you have better solutions.

Comment: `std::bind1st`/`std::bind2nd` ?

Comment: std::bind is a function call. It doesn't create a new type, something very easy to use

Comment: @Quentin I added C++11 in the tags list:)

Comment: can you show how you use `EqualTo` in your code? why do you need the new comparator to be a type?

Comment: @m.s. I'm using the functors like this: TimeElapsed(Less<float>(1.f)) or MovesPerformed(EqualTo<int>(5)) where TimeElapsed or MovesPerformed accept std::function<bool(...)> as parameter

Comment: Sounds like a lambda: `[](float timeElapsed) { return timeElapsed < 1.f;}`. A lambda is just a convenient notation to create a functor object with some unnamed type.

Comment: @MSalters exactly like a lambda, but it won't be used by programmers. Is just a simple system to be used by designers. The expressivity of the construct is very important. In the real system we have using for the type and it looks almost like a natural language: TimeElapsed(Less(1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11, this is as good as it gets. But I'd rather expect the predicate to be directly constructed at the call site :

```
std::find_if(begin(v), end(v), [limit](int i) { return i < limit; });
```

In C++14, you could use return type deduction to make a factory fuction :

```
template <class Comp>
auto predicate(typename Comp::second_argument_type rhs) {
    return [c = Comp{}, rhs](typename Comp::first_argument_type lhs) {
        return c(lhs, rhs);
    };
}
```

Example call : `predicate<std::less<int>>(4)` returns the function object.

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/053a31f6dfa33f13)

Answer (score 1):

@Quentins answer can also be made compilable in C++11 using `std::function` as the return type which the lambdas are convertible to:

```
template <class Comp>
std::function<typename Comp::result_type (typename Comp::first_argument_type)> predicate(typename Comp::second_argument_type rhs)
{
    return [rhs](typename Comp::first_argument_type lhs){
        Comp c{};
        return c(lhs, rhs);
    };
}
```

[<kbd>live on coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/017206273033ab49)